# Is there anyway i can search for a text in an xml Angular. The xml is loaded as the innerHTML of my div

Tags: javascript, angular, xml, full-text-search

Is there anyway i can search for a text in an xml . The xml is loaded as the inner HTML of my div .i want to implement something like the "FIND IN PAGE" or a search which searches for a  text in the XML rendered as html.

This is my component.ts code

```
        let xmld = this.sharedService.getXMLData();
        this.htmlData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(xmld);
```

The getXMLData() function reads the XML file and it is placed  in the xmld variable.

This is my component.html code

```
    <div [innerHTML]="htmlData">

    </div>
```

This is the test XML i am using 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml

The below given is the result that i need.When i search a word say "Trillium" it should be highlighted as given below.I need a procedure to search the XML in my html page.

[image]
This is what i need.I have tried many methods.There is no issue if i am searching in plain HTML.The issue is when the XML as loaded as the html. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share an example of xml which is getting loaded in this. And what string you are trying to search which is not appearing in the results?

Comment: @ArchitGarg Hi Thanks , I have updated the question and have added the test XML. Kindly take a look.